# How to check if go template utilizes ALL template data

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's say I have a template string

```golang
today i visited {{ .market }} to buy {{ .fruit }}
```

and the provided template data is

```golang
map[string]string := { market: "whole foods", fruit: "bananas", veg: "celery" }
```

I want to panic here since `.veg` is not used in the template string. Is this possible?

I am using go templates (`text/template`).

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ -- No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no builtin support for it. You could analyze the parsed template, but it's unnecessarily complex. Also note that this static analyzis could never be complete: a template may access data based on runtime parameters, and whether everything is used could only be decided at runtime, and may vary from execution to execution (e.g. a map value may be indexed using `{{index .someMap .someKey}}` where `someKey` is a value provided at runtime).

An acceptable solution could be to pass a data structure that tracks which elements are accessed, and you can check that after the template execution and do whatever you want to if not everything was used.

For example this structure tracks which elements were not yet accessed:

```
type Params struct {
    m, remaining map[string]string
}

func NewParams(m map[string]string) *Params {
    return &Params{
        m:         m,
        remaining: maps.Clone(m),
    }
}

func (p *Params) Get(key string) string {
    delete(p.remaining, key)
    return p.m[key]
}
```

Example using it:

```
const src = `today i visited {{ .Get "market" }} to buy {{ .Get "fruit" }}`
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

m := NewParams(
    map[string]string{"market": "whole foods", "fruit": "bananas", "veg": "celery"},
)

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println()
if len(m.remaining) > 0 {
    fmt.Println("Following entries were not used:", m.remaining)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/C9h1ux2-i39)):

```
today i visited whole foods to buy bananas
Following entries were not used: map[veg:celery]
```

Note that I used 2 maps (`m` and `remaining`) to allow accessing the same elements multiple times. If each element could only be accessed once, a simple map (and removing elements from that map) would also work.